# Elasticsearch Not Responding to Certain API Calls / Kibana and Head not loading

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch cluster running 1.2.2 with head and Kibana 3.1.2 installed.  When i load Kibana in my browser, the header of the page loads, but not the body of the default page.  If I attempt to open an existing dashboard, I see the list of saved dashboards, but cannot get one to load.

The Head plugin also will not load.

The /_cat/health returns promptly with cluster status of green.
The /_cat/nodes just hangs up and will not return.
Other calls to the api such as an -XDELETE hangs, while an -XGET will return data.

I have had this issue before and it mysteriously resolves itself.  I have been unable to find a root cause.  Has anyone experienced this and found cause?

Comment: Which version of Kibana?

Comment: Kibana version 3.1.2

Answer (score 0):

Stopping the dedicated master nodes and the dedicated client node at the same time, and then bringing them back up seems to have solved this issue.  A rolling restart of the masters and client was not effective.