# Timeouts with 503 response in Elasticsearch for part of the _cat API

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a quite large elasticsearch cluster with more than 100 nodes, and I have a problem when sometimes the cluster starts returning 504 http codes and timing out for requests to the _cat API, in particular `/_cat/indices` and `/_cat/shards`. As a result, KOPF it's not loading, I guess because it calls this same API under the hood. This happens even when the cluster is green, and it's only solved when I restart the cluster. Indexing and search, even from Kibana, work ok, as well as other APIs like `_cluster/health?level=shards` and `_cat/nodes`

I'm using Elasticsearch 1.7.1, any idea why this might be happening? I know I have to upgrade the version, but I would like to understand what it's going on here.

Note this question is similar to [Elasticsearch Not Responding to Certain API Calls / Kibana and Head not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33657841/elasticsearch-not-responding-to-certain-api-calls-kibana-and-head-not-loading), but that question hasn't been answered yet.

Comment: This discussion might be useful. https://discuss.elastic.co/t/frustrated-with-rest-api/19045

Comment: Can you update your question with the result you get from `curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_nodes/thread_pool` when you see such behavior?

Comment: Hm... 100 nodes is a largeish number. Do you have aliases defined? If so, how many? For this many nodes I assume you also have dedicated master nodes. What are the hw specs of the dedicated master nodes? (cpus, memory, heap). Your nodes each has a dedicated machine at its disposal?

Comment: Our biggest cluster has 212 nodes. The cluster is running on EC2 using i2.2xlarge instances (8 vCPU, 61 GB RAM) for the data and master nodes. We have dedicated masters, all the nodes just run the elasticseach daemon, and a Ganglia-style monitoring daemon, nothing else. We also move older indices to d2.2xlarge (8 vCPU, 61 GB RAM) that have bigger but slower (HHD) disks. We have an index per day with 5 alias per index, 3 of them are filtered aliases with a filter than is an or on a fixed set of document types

Comment: How is the heap usage of the elected master node when you run those commands? Do you see `[gc]` messages in the log file of the elected master node? How is the CPU of the same node when you run that command?